# Backup MS SQL Server database through Java program?

Tags: java, sql-server

My question is simple. There's any possible that I follow the process through to completion.

A command like that

```
backup database master to disk='\\csd0201wnt29f\backup\master.bak' with stats=1
```

I mean the `stats=1` clause.

The method

```
 public void executar(Backup bkp, String comando) throws Exception {
        Connection conexao = ConnectionFactory.connectBase(bkp.getServidor(), bkp.getUsuario(), bkp.getSenha());
        PreparedStatement cmd = conexao.prepareCall(comando, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        PreparedStatement cmdQuery = conexao.prepareCall("select @@spid");
        ResultSet set = cmdQuery.executeQuery();
        int spid=0;
        if (set.next()) {
            spid=set.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("SPID" + set.getInt(1));
        }
        SQLMonitor s = new SQLMonitor(bkp, spid);
        s.start();
        cmd.execute();        

        cmdQuery.close();        
        cmd.close();
        conexao.close();
    }
```

The call

```
 public void RealizaBackup(Backup bkp) throws Exception {
        SQLComando cmd = new SQLComando();

        System.out.println("backup database " + bkp.getBase() + " to disk='" + bkp.getCaminho() + "\\" + bkp.getBase() + ".bak' with stats=1");
        cmd.executar(bkp, "backup database " + bkp.getBase() + " to disk='" + bkp.getCaminho() + "\\" + bkp.getBase() + ".bak' with stats=1");
    }
```

Comment: where are you stuck? what you did already?

Comment: The backup was done, but I cound't follow the progress return by the sql server

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: @EvgenyLebedev i add the code